# concourse git-resource : tag_filter and tag_regex not working

Tags: git, concourse, concourse-git-resource

I have a list of git tags

```
0.0.1
0.0.1-rc.0
0.0.1-rc.1
0.1.0
0.10.0
0.10.1-rc.0
0.11.0
0.11.1-rc.0
0.12.0
0.12.1-rc.0
0.13.0
0.13.1-hotfix.0
0.13.1-rc.0
0.14.0
0.14.1-rc.0
0.15.0
0.15.1-rc.0
0.16.0
0.16.1-rc.0
0.17.0
0.17.1-rc.0
0.18.0
0.18.1-hotfix.0
```

from these tags I want to get only the following tags:

```
0.0.1, 0.1.0, 0.10.0 , 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.14.0, 0.15.0, 0.16.0, 0.17.0, 0.18.0, 0.10.0
```

I declared my resource as follow :

```
- name: git-filtered
  type: git
  icon: bitbucket
  source:
    uri: ssh://((git-url))
    private_key: ((git-key))
    branch: master
    fetch_tags: true
    tag_regex: "[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+"
```

and I have tried all these solutions :

```
#    tag_regex: "[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+"
#    tag_filter: "[0-9].??.[0-9]"
#    tag_filter: "*([0-9])\\.*([0-9])\\.*([0-9])"
#    tag_filter: "*([0-9])\.*([0-9])\.*([0-9])"
#    tag_filter: "*([0-9]).*([0-9]).*([0-9])"
#    tag_regex: "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"
#    tag_regex: "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"
#    tag_regex: "[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]"
#    tag_regex: "[0123456789]+.[0123456789]+.[0123456789]+"
#    tag_filter: "[0-9].??.[0-9]"
```

none of them seems to filter the digits as I want (digits.digits.digits).

I have used this line as reference to build my filter : https://github.com/concourse/git-resource/blob/master/assets/check#L168.

Any idea ?

Comment: `tag_filter` is used in [`git tag --list`](https://github.com/concourse/git-resource/blob/30c1e237dd9f919c71230501c771b4188383b51d/assets/check#L141) so it must be a glob (fnmatch) pattern. `[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]` is the best you can do. Disadvantage: single digits.

Comment: `tag_regex` is used in [`grep -E`](https://github.com/concourse/git-resource/blob/30c1e237dd9f919c71230501c771b4188383b51d/assets/check#L161) so it must be an extended regular expression. The 1st one `[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+` and the 2nd one `[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+` look good (may be with a single backslash instead of double). In what way they don't work? Don't select enough or select too many?

Comment: when I've used [[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+, it gave me single digits with tag_filter, but gave me the last commit with tag_regex - and not the last tag . as if the tag_regex is not doing anything

Comment: I found my isse, our concourse used git-resource version 1.7.2 which not  contains git-regex, I forced the git-resource to 1.12.0 and all works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was wrong.

The tag_regex was introduced since the version 1.11.0 of git-resource.

Our concourse server uses an older version of git resource. So I forced the version as follow :

```
  - name: git
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: concourse/git-resource
      tag: "1.12.0"
```

and now the filter using regex is working properly :

```
tag_regex: '[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+'
```